# What are some creative uses of the orange brick separator tool?

Tags: building, tools, brick-separator

I have these piling up around my LEGO corner:

[image: lego brick tool]

Any suggestions for creative uses? Especially multiple?

Comment: Gawsh I have 5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have seen a number of very creative builds with the orange brick separator. Here are some examples:

Spaceship by F@bz: http://www.flickr.com/photos/fabz71/12434428513/

Mech by Lewis Meeny: http://www.flickr.com/photos/tr0jinh0rse/11318913594/

Deep Sea Explorer by Keith Reed: http://www.flickr.com/photos/keithreed/12943153094/

And my favorite is this Clown Fish X-wing by dr-spock-888: http://www.flickr.com/photos/dr_spock_888/20558633496/

And there is also the super secret worship room of the cult of the Followers of One Long Orange Object or FOOLOO by cimddwc: http://www.flickr.com/photos/cimddwc/24779936911/

Answer (score 14):

How about a Minifig scale playground slide?

[image]

There is a connection point for an Technic Axle connector to provide the support for the slide and two stud connections to add a ladder.

Comment: Oh I _love_ this

Answer (score 8):

To add to TheBrickBlogger's suggestions, F@bz has another spaceship that I believe is worth mentioning: https://www.flickr.com/photos/fabz71/21111423905/

I recall seeing an awesome dinosaur made almost entirely out of Brick Separators on Flickr a while back (and I believe it was called a Separatosaurus) but all my searches have been futile so far. That said, google "Brick Separator MOC" and you can see many designs.

Comment: The space ship is really cool.

Comment: Oh, wow! How did I miss that one! So much orange goodness! Faved! I will also keep an eye out for that Separatosaurus. :D

Answer (score 7):

One thing I've been using some of my brick separators for is in the construction of wedges for robotics and competition builds. The semi-sharp prying edge is sharper than most parts, and the angle is decent enough for a low wedge.

[image]

They have no strong connectors of their own, but the height of the brick edge is 2 plates tall, meaning it will fit well between 2 Technic bricks, with Technic pieces holding them together.

[image]

With a design like this, you can easily connect it to a Technic beam, with it freely swinging down to make ground contact.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Transport Terminal]

This is a good idea for brick separators!

Answer (score 3):

I use them to get stubborn batteries out of remotes, to open stiff ports on device cases, and to get under tabs on soda cans....I want one on a keychain!