# What is this old dark grey LEGO wedge piece with a grooved handle?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Here is an odd piece that I have found - any idea what it is? 2x2 plate is shown for scale.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a *LEGO* brick Separator tool. Mostly used to preserve the structural integrity of the human nail, teeth, gum line etc...

Watch the classical use of it [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Thx6RoONnE).

[image]

[*Here*](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7340/what-are-some-creative-uses-of-the-orange-brick-separator-tool)'s a recent post of some unorthodox uses of the Separator tool.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To expand on a previous answer, it is the [original brick separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6007&idColor=6#T=C) that was produced between 1996 and 2011 in two colors. It was replaced in 2012 by [a different part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=96874&idColor=4#T=C) with the same name and purpose but slightly different features.

[image]

Comment: It is always orange, but one of the only sets which have the part in a different color is 80013. I just noticed right now.

Comment: @mindstormsboi You might want to clarify your comment. First of all, my answer is to the question about what the part in the question's image is, which is the original brick separator which does NOT come in orange.Second, your comment both says that the new separator is always in orange and also that it comes in a second color. Both statements can not be true. :-)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, and besides that I've already found some other sets that have this piece in a different color. But it doesn't matter.